# Pull request based jenkins job trigger using generic webhook plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, google-kubernetes-engine, continuous-deployment

I am trying to trigger a jenkins pipeline job only when a pull request has been approved & merged to a specific github branch in our CI/CD implementation.

currently whenever i merge a PR to *release*, jenkins job that is created to get triggered when PR is merged to *master* is also getting triggered, while I only want *release* jenkins job to be triggered.

strangely *echo env.GIT_BRANCH* cmd shows branch name as MASTER in *master* job parallelly *release* job shows branch as RELEASE when i only merged PR to release.

Things tried:

1. *Branches to build* feature in Jenkins
2. *when* condition in Jenkinsfile (its acting weird, both staging and production jobs are getting triggered when one branch is targetted)

Environment:
*Jenkins ver. 2.176.3, Docker,Generic webhook trigger* for Jenkins

I'm convinced that when condition will work, but for me it isn't, following is my partial *when* condition in Jenkinsfile:

```
stage("Step 1: Build Docker"){}
stage("Step 2: Push to DockerHub"){}
stage("Step 3: Production Deployment"){
            when {
                expression { return params.current_status == "closed" && params.merged == true && env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/master" }
            }
            steps{
                -----
                sh 'kubectl apply -f **.yaml'
            }
}
```

In my jenkinsfile I'm writing logic to deploy my docker images to kubernetes cluster, so all that i  am looking for is to accurately trigger the job based on the branch.

Any suggestions on how to get it to work, what am i missing here?

Note: I had asked the same question earlier, but has to rewrite as it wasn't clear.

Comment: One way to work around that is to check the correct branch on the other side in a github/bitbucket/gitlab pipeline which only triggers the webhook when the right branch was merged. The other option would be to check it in the pipeline `if (branch != 'release') currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'`

Comment: Can you please clarify, why this  -> currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'?

Comment: This aborts the current build when the branch is wrong. As far as I know it's the best way to do that in declarative pipelines. Another approach would be to create a pipeline that is only there to be triggered by webhooks and filter out the ones that should actually start the build+deploy job